# HTML code does not display the image in email

Tags: python, html

I have the below HTML code that I am passing through a python script to send out an email. I am able to get the email however I am trying to have an image added to the body of the email but I see that the image does not get added to the email. I have the image saved to a variable called `image` and I am trying to call this variable. It just shows a greyed out area in the position where the image needs to be shown.

```
image = 'file.png'

f""" 
<html>
   <body style="background-color:#fafafa;">
      <div class="row">
         <div style="float:left;width: 20%;padding: 10px;">
         </div>
         div align="center" style="float:left;width: 60%;padding: 10px;">
         <img src="cid:image" align="middle" width="253" height="68">
         <br>
         <h1 style="color:#9FA6B5;font-family:sans-serif;font-weight:200;text-align: center;">{name}</h1>
      </div>
      <div style="float:left;width: 20%;padding: 10px;">
      </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>"""
```

Comment: The source (`src`) of the `img` tag needs to be a URL from which the email client can load the image from

Comment: Make sure the url is absolute, not relative to your project. Otherwise it will not work from everywhere...

Comment: @IainShelvington, can't I call the image from my local path..

Comment: @scottmartin no you can't. When the client loads the email in their client they will only have the contents of the email as a reference as to which images to load. Local/relative paths to images do not make sense in this context (relative to what?). You have to make the image available on a web accessible URL and use this URL as the img source

Comment: @IainShelvington thanks for that explanation. Assuming that I have a web based URL do I need to edit `<img src="cid:image"` with `<img src="cid:web_path` or does it need any other edit.

Comment: you could try to convert image to string base64 and embed it in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You given the local path of the image, which can not be send to your email, you have to give path of the image from server image folder to show your image.

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload your images to a server image then include the path into your `src` tag.
Here is a [server](https://imgbb.com/) i use to upload images for HTML email templates.